# How can I printed the member of object in GDB when I used debug mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In A.h

```
@interface A {
    NSString *str;
}
```

In B.h

```
@interface B {
    A *a;
}
```

I set a breakpoint in a function of B.

I wanted to print the str of a in GDB.

How can I do that.

"po a.str" is not worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `po a->str`. Note the difference between this (which accesses the variable directly) and `po [a str]`, which calls the method `-str` which you may or may not have implemented to return `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `[a str]`, if you have a getter method called `str`, or you could `@synthesize` the `NSString *str`.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `po [a str]`
or
    `po [[b a] str]`